# Python - NameError (двунаправленный связный список)

Tags: python, двусвязный-список

Правильно ли я реализую двунаправленный связный список и, если да, то как исправить ошибку?

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, value, name, prev, next):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

E = Cell(5, "E", D, None)
D = Cell(4, "D", C, E)
C = Cell(3, "C", B, D)
B = Cell(2, "B", A, C)
A = Cell(1, "A", None, B)
```

> NameError: name 'D' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути, однако если конструктор списка будет принимать и предыдущую и следующую вершины, то возникнет циклическая зависимость. Возможным решением может быть убирание `prev` и `next` из конструктора и вынос их установки в отдельный метод:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, value, name):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name

    def set_prev_and_next(self, prev, next):
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next


A = Cell(1, 'A')
B = Cell(2, 'B')
C = Cell(3, 'C')
D = Cell(4, 'D')
E = Cell(5, 'E')

A.set_prev_and_next(E, B)
B.set_prev_and_next(A, C)
C.set_prev_and_next(B, D)
D.set_prev_and_next(C, E)
E.set_prev_and_next(D, A)
```

Однако в таком случае вам нужно будет каждый раз ручками заботиться о том, чтобы значения `prev` и `next` были согласованы. Например, если вы захотите вставить элемент в середину списка, то вам нужно будет вызвать метод `set_prev_and_next` у трёх элементов: вставляемого, предыдущего и следующего. Гораздо лучшим вариантом будет написать метод вроде `insert_after`, который будет вставлять элемент после некоторого элемента и сам обрабатывать согласованность значений `prev` и `next`. Например, так:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, value, name):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

    def insert_after(self, cell):
        if self.next is None:
            cell.prev = self
            cell.next = self
            self.prev = cell
            self.next = cell
        else:
            cell.prev = self
            cell.next = self.next
            self.next = next
            cell.next.prev = cell


A = Cell(1, 'A')
B = Cell(2, 'B')
C = Cell(3, 'C')
D = Cell(4, 'D')
E = Cell(5, 'E')

B.insert_after(A)
C.insert_after(B)
D.insert_after(C)
E.insert_after(D)
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас не получится вызвать переменную до ее определения, необходимо изменить порядок,чтобы интерпретатор знал куда вы обращаетесь, так работать не будет

```
E = Cell(5, "E", D, None)
D = Cell(4, "D", C, E)
C = Cell(3, "C", B, D)
B = Cell(2, "B", A, C)
A = Cell(1, "A", None, B)
```

можно попробовать изменить логику, я могу ошибаться и буду благадарен за правки более опытных участников

```
class Constr(object):
    def __init__(self, value, name, prev=None):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = None

    def add_next(self, obj):
        self.next = obj

    def show(self):
        answer = dict(name=self.name, value=self.value, prev=self.prev, next=self.next)
        return answer


class Contain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_obj = []

    def update_obj(self, value, name):
        if not self.all_obj:
            new = Constr(value, name)
            self.all_obj.append(new)
        else:
            update_obj = self.all_obj[-1]
            new_obj = Constr(value, name, prev=update_obj)
            update_obj.add_next(new_obj)
            self.all_obj.append(new_obj)
        return True

    def get_list(self):
        if self.all_obj:
            return [i.show() or None for i in self.all_obj]
        return []

test = Contain()

test.update_obj(1, 'hello')
test.update_obj(2, 'world')
test.update_obj(3, '!')

test.get_list()
```